# Trouble building executable uber jar with Maven and Subetha SMTP and LOG4J

Tags: java, maven, smtp, log4j, maven-shade-plugin

I'm new to maven, and trying to create an application which uses the [Subetha SMTP library][1], and package the entire app into one executable app.

To do the packaging I am attempting to use [Mavens Shade plugin][2], but am running into an issue with one of the libraries which Subetha SMTP is using/including.

The project seems to build fine:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ smtpServer ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\dev\apps\smtpServer\target\smtpServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:1.7:shade (default) @ smtpServer ---
[INFO] Including org.subethamail:subethasmtp:jar:3.1.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.4 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6 in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing D:\dev\apps\smtpServer\target\smtpServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar with D:\dev\apps\smtpServer\target\smtpServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.959s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jun 04 15:11:28 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/24M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
D:\dev\apps\smtpServer>
```

But when I run it I get:

```
D:\dev\apps\smtpServer\target>java -jar smtpServer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Starting Up...
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:189)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:112)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:105)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:235)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:208)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:221)
        at org.subethamail.smtp.server.SMTPServer.<clinit>(SMTPServer.java:49)
        at com.rim.hms.smtpServer.App.main(App.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more
```

The error message instructs me to place the SL4J jar on the classpath, which I had tried, but the issue isn't resolved.

Here is my pom.xml for the project (I've tried both specifying the slf4j, which is the one causing the problem, as well as removing it):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <parent>
        <groupId>com.foo.bar.apps</groupId>
        <artifactId>apps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.foo.bar.apps.smtpServer</groupId>
  <artifactId>smtpServer</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>smtpServer</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.subethamail</groupId>
        <artifactId>subethasmtp</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.foo.bar.smtpServer.App</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


</project>
```

Here is the contents of the created JAR file:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
com/
com/foo/
com/foo/bar/
com/foo/bar/smtpServer/
com/foo/bar/smtpServer/App.class
com/foo/bar/smtpServer/DumbMessageHandlerFactory$Handler.class
com/foo/bar/smtpServer/DumbMessageHandlerFactory.class
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.foo.bar.apps.smtpServer/
META-INF/maven/com.foo.bar.apps.smtpServer/smtpServer/
META-INF/maven/com.foo.bar.apps.smtpServer/smtpServer/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.foo.bar.apps.smtpServer/smtpServer/pom.properties
org/
org/subethamail/
org/subethamail/smtp/
org/subethamail/smtp/auth/
org/subethamail/smtp/auth/EasyAuthenticationHandlerFactory.class
org/subethamail/smtp/auth/LoginAuthenticationHandlerFactory$Handler.class
org/subethamail/smtp/auth/LoginAuthenticationHandlerFactory.class
org/subethamail/smtp/auth/LoginFailedException.class
org/subethamail/smtp/auth/MultipleAuthenticationHandlerFactory$Handler.class
org/subethamail/smtp/auth/MultipleAuthenticationHandlerFactory.class
org/subethamail/smtp/auth/PlainAuthenticationHandlerFactory$Handler.class
org/subethamail/smtp/auth/PlainAuthenticationHandlerFactory.class
org/subethamail/smtp/auth/UsernamePasswordValidator.class
org/subethamail/smtp/AuthenticationHandler.class
org/subethamail/smtp/AuthenticationHandlerFactory.class
org/subethamail/smtp/client/
org/subethamail/smtp/client/SmartClient.class
org/subethamail/smtp/client/SMTPClient$Response.class
org/subethamail/smtp/client/SMTPClient.class
org/subethamail/smtp/client/SMTPException.class
org/subethamail/smtp/command/
org/subethamail/smtp/command/AuthCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/command/DataCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/command/EhloCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/command/HelloCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/command/HelpCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/command/MailCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/command/NoopCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/command/QuitCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/command/ReceiptCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/command/ResetCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/command/StartTLSCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/command/VerifyCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/DropConnectionException.class
org/subethamail/smtp/helper/
org/subethamail/smtp/helper/SimpleMessageListener.class
org/subethamail/smtp/helper/SimpleMessageListenerAdapter$Delivery.class
org/subethamail/smtp/helper/SimpleMessageListenerAdapter$Handler.class
org/subethamail/smtp/helper/SimpleMessageListenerAdapter.class
org/subethamail/smtp/helper/SmarterMessageListener$Receiver.class
org/subethamail/smtp/helper/SmarterMessageListener.class
org/subethamail/smtp/helper/SmarterMessageListenerAdapter$Handler.class
org/subethamail/smtp/helper/SmarterMessageListenerAdapter.class
org/subethamail/smtp/io/
org/subethamail/smtp/io/BetterByteArrayOutputStream.class
org/subethamail/smtp/io/CRLFOutputStream.class
org/subethamail/smtp/io/CRLFTerminatedReader$MaxLineLengthException.class
org/subethamail/smtp/io/CRLFTerminatedReader$TerminationException.class
org/subethamail/smtp/io/CRLFTerminatedReader.class
org/subethamail/smtp/io/DeferredFileOutputStream.class
org/subethamail/smtp/io/DotTerminatedInputStream.class
org/subethamail/smtp/io/DotTerminatedOutputStream.class
org/subethamail/smtp/io/DotUnstuffingInputStream.class
org/subethamail/smtp/io/ExtraDotOutputStream.class
org/subethamail/smtp/io/ReceivedHeaderStream.class
org/subethamail/smtp/io/ThresholdingOutputStream.class
org/subethamail/smtp/MessageContext.class
org/subethamail/smtp/MessageHandler.class
org/subethamail/smtp/MessageHandlerFactory.class
org/subethamail/smtp/RejectException.class
org/subethamail/smtp/server/
org/subethamail/smtp/server/BaseCommand.class
org/subethamail/smtp/server/Command.class
org/subethamail/smtp/server/CommandException.class
org/subethamail/smtp/server/CommandHandler.class
org/subethamail/smtp/server/CommandRegistry.class
org/subethamail/smtp/server/HelpMessage.class
org/subethamail/smtp/server/InvalidCommandNameException.class
org/subethamail/smtp/server/RequireTLSCommandWrapper.class
org/subethamail/smtp/server/ServerThread.class
org/subethamail/smtp/server/Session.class
org/subethamail/smtp/server/SMTPServer.class
org/subethamail/smtp/server/UnknownCommandException.class
org/subethamail/smtp/TooMuchDataException.class
org/subethamail/smtp/util/
org/subethamail/smtp/util/Base64.class
org/subethamail/smtp/util/EmailUtils.class
org/subethamail/smtp/util/TextUtils.class
org/subethamail/smtp/Version.class
org/subethamail/wiser/
org/subethamail/wiser/Wiser.class
org/subethamail/wiser/WiserMessage.class
META-INF/maven/org.subethamail/
META-INF/maven/org.subethamail/subethasmtp/
META-INF/maven/org.subethamail/subethasmtp/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/org.subethamail/subethasmtp/pom.properties
javax/
javax/mail/
javax/mail/EventQueue$QueueElement.class
javax/mail/Flags$Flag.class
javax/mail/Service$TerminatorEvent.class
javax/mail/Service.class
javax/mail/FolderClosedException.class
javax/mail/Folder$TerminatorEvent.class
javax/mail/MessageContext.class
javax/mail/Session$3.class
javax/mail/FetchProfile.class
javax/mail/Provider.class
javax/mail/UIDFolder$FetchProfileItem.class
javax/mail/internet/
javax/mail/internet/ParseException.class
javax/mail/internet/ParameterList.class
javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.class
javax/mail/internet/MailDateParser.class
javax/mail/internet/UniqueValue.class
javax/mail/internet/MailDateFormat.class
javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.class
javax/mail/internet/ParameterList$Value.class
javax/mail/internet/ParameterList$MultiValue.class
javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.class
javax/mail/internet/SharedInputStream.class
javax/mail/internet/HeaderTokenizer.class
javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.class
javax/mail/internet/InternetHeaders$InternetHeader.class
javax/mail/internet/InternetHeaders.class
javax/mail/internet/NewsAddress.class
javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility$1NullInputStream.class
javax/mail/internet/HeaderTokenizer$Token.class
javax/mail/internet/PreencodedMimeBodyPart.class
javax/mail/internet/AsciiOutputStream.class
javax/mail/internet/InternetHeaders$matchEnum.class
javax/mail/internet/ParameterList$ToStringBuffer.class
javax/mail/internet/MimePart.class
javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler.class
javax/mail/internet/MimePartDataSource.class
javax/mail/internet/ParameterList$1.class
javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage$RecipientType.class
javax/mail/internet/ContentType.class
javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.class
javax/mail/internet/AddressException.class
javax/mail/internet/ParameterList$ParamEnum.class
javax/mail/internet/ContentDisposition.class
javax/mail/IllegalWriteException.class
javax/mail/Quota.class
javax/mail/Version.class
javax/mail/Session$2.class
javax/mail/Part.class
javax/mail/BodyPart.class
javax/mail/Message$RecipientType.class
javax/mail/UIDFolder.class
javax/mail/Transport.class
javax/mail/AuthenticationFailedException.class
javax/mail/Quota$Resource.class
javax/mail/Session$1.class
javax/mail/Multipart.class
javax/mail/EventQueue.class
javax/mail/PasswordAuthentication.class
javax/mail/Authenticator.class
javax/mail/ReadOnlyFolderException.class
javax/mail/Folder.class
javax/mail/FetchProfile$Item.class
javax/mail/FolderNotFoundException.class
javax/mail/MessageAware.class
javax/mail/MultipartDataSource.class
javax/mail/event/
javax/mail/event/FolderEvent.class
javax/mail/event/TransportListener.class
javax/mail/event/MessageCountListener.class
javax/mail/event/MailEvent.class
javax/mail/event/MessageChangedEvent.class
javax/mail/event/TransportAdapter.class
javax/mail/event/ConnectionEvent.class
javax/mail/event/MessageCountEvent.class
javax/mail/event/TransportEvent.class
javax/mail/event/FolderListener.class
javax/mail/event/MessageChangedListener.class
javax/mail/event/StoreEvent.class
javax/mail/event/FolderAdapter.class
javax/mail/event/ConnectionAdapter.class
javax/mail/event/ConnectionListener.class
javax/mail/event/StoreListener.class
javax/mail/event/MessageCountAdapter.class
javax/mail/search/
javax/mail/search/NotTerm.class
javax/mail/search/MessageNumberTerm.class
javax/mail/search/HeaderTerm.class
javax/mail/search/ComparisonTerm.class
javax/mail/search/IntegerComparisonTerm.class
javax/mail/search/BodyTerm.class
javax/mail/search/FromTerm.class
javax/mail/search/StringTerm.class
javax/mail/search/SentDateTerm.class
javax/mail/search/RecipientTerm.class
javax/mail/search/AndTerm.class
javax/mail/search/FlagTerm.class
javax/mail/search/MessageIDTerm.class
javax/mail/search/SubjectTerm.class
javax/mail/search/AddressTerm.class
javax/mail/search/SearchException.class
javax/mail/search/OrTerm.class
javax/mail/search/RecipientStringTerm.class
javax/mail/search/ReceivedDateTerm.class
javax/mail/search/FromStringTerm.class
javax/mail/search/DateTerm.class
javax/mail/search/AddressStringTerm.class
javax/mail/search/SearchTerm.class
javax/mail/search/SizeTerm.class
javax/mail/MessageRemovedException.class
javax/mail/Store.class
javax/mail/Session$7.class
javax/mail/NoSuchProviderException.class
javax/mail/URLName.class
javax/mail/StreamLoader.class
javax/mail/Address.class
javax/mail/StoreClosedException.class
javax/mail/MessagingException.class
javax/mail/Session$6.class
javax/mail/Provider$Type.class
javax/mail/Session.class
javax/mail/MethodNotSupportedException.class
javax/mail/Message.class
javax/mail/Session$5.class
javax/mail/QuotaAwareStore.class
javax/mail/Header.class
javax/mail/Session$4.class
javax/mail/util/
javax/mail/util/SharedFileInputStream.class
javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.class
javax/mail/util/SharedByteArrayInputStream.class
javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource$DSByteArrayOutputStream.class
javax/mail/util/SharedFileInputStream$SharedFile.class
javax/mail/Flags.class
javax/mail/SendFailedException.class
com/sun/
com/sun/mail/
com/sun/mail/smtp/
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPSSLTransport.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPMessage.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPAddressSucceededException.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport$PlainAuthenticator.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPAddressFailedException.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPSendFailedException.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPOutputStream.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPSenderFailedException.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport$LoginAuthenticator.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPSaslAuthenticator.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SaslAuthenticator.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport$NtlmAuthenticator.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport$DigestMD5Authenticator.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPSaslAuthenticator$1.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/DigestMD5.class
com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport$Authenticator.class
com/sun/mail/imap/
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPNestedMessage.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$10.class
com/sun/mail/imap/Rights$Right.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPMessage$1FetchProfileCondition.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$2.class
com/sun/mail/imap/MessageLiteral.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$11.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$3.class
com/sun/mail/imap/DefaultFolder$2.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPInputStream.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$ProtocolCommand.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPStore$1.class
com/sun/mail/imap/ACL.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$12.class
com/sun/mail/imap/DefaultFolder$1.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$13.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPStore$ConnectionPool.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPBodyPart.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$1.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$18.class
com/sun/mail/imap/LengthCounter.class
com/sun/mail/imap/MessageCache.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$14.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPStore.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPMultipartDataSource.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$6.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$19.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPMessage.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPSSLStore.class
com/sun/mail/imap/Rights.class
com/sun/mail/imap/DefaultFolder.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$15.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$7.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$16.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/IMAPAddress.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/ListInfo.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/SearchSequence.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/SaslAuthenticator.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/MessageSet.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/Namespaces.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/BASE64MailboxEncoder.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/BODY.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/ENVELOPE.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/IMAPSaslAuthenticator.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/Namespaces$Namespace.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/IMAPProtocol.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/MailboxInfo.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/IMAPResponse.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/BASE64MailboxDecoder.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/Status.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/Item.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/UID.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/FetchResponse.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/BODYSTRUCTURE.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/INTERNALDATE.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/RFC822DATA.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/RFC822SIZE.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/FLAGS.class
com/sun/mail/imap/protocol/UIDSet.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$FetchProfileItem.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$8.class
com/sun/mail/imap/Utility.class
com/sun/mail/imap/AppendUID.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$4.class
com/sun/mail/imap/Utility$Condition.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$17.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$9.class
com/sun/mail/imap/SortTerm.class
com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder$5.class
com/sun/mail/iap/
com/sun/mail/iap/CommandFailedException.class
com/sun/mail/iap/Argument.class
com/sun/mail/iap/ResponseHandler.class
com/sun/mail/iap/ConnectionException.class
com/sun/mail/iap/ResponseInputStream.class
com/sun/mail/iap/ProtocolException.class
com/sun/mail/iap/ByteArray.class
com/sun/mail/iap/AString.class
com/sun/mail/iap/Response.class
com/sun/mail/iap/LiteralException.class
com/sun/mail/iap/Literal.class
com/sun/mail/iap/ParsingException.class
com/sun/mail/iap/Atom.class
com/sun/mail/iap/Protocol.class
com/sun/mail/iap/BadCommandException.class
com/sun/mail/auth/
com/sun/mail/auth/MD4.class
com/sun/mail/auth/Ntlm.class
com/sun/mail/handlers/
com/sun/mail/handlers/multipart_mixed.class
com/sun/mail/handlers/text_plain.class
com/sun/mail/handlers/image_gif.class
com/sun/mail/handlers/text_plain$NoCloseOutputStream.class
com/sun/mail/handlers/text_html.class
com/sun/mail/handlers/text_xml.class
com/sun/mail/handlers/image_jpeg.class
com/sun/mail/handlers/message_rfc822.class
com/sun/mail/util/
com/sun/mail/util/PropUtil.class
com/sun/mail/util/BASE64EncoderStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/TraceOutputStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/UUDecoderStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/LineOutputStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/MailSSLSocketFactory$1.class
com/sun/mail/util/BEncoderStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/QPDecoderStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/QEncoderStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/LineInputStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/FolderClosedIOException.class
com/sun/mail/util/MailSSLSocketFactory$MailTrustManager.class
com/sun/mail/util/UUEncoderStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/SocketFetcher$1.class
com/sun/mail/util/QDecoderStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/QPEncoderStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/MimeUtil$1.class
com/sun/mail/util/MessageRemovedIOException.class
com/sun/mail/util/logging/
com/sun/mail/util/logging/LogManagerProperties.class
com/sun/mail/util/logging/LogManagerProperties$1.class
com/sun/mail/util/logging/MailHandler.class
com/sun/mail/util/logging/MailHandler$TailNameFormatter.class
com/sun/mail/util/MailSSLSocketFactory.class
com/sun/mail/util/SocketFetcher.class
com/sun/mail/util/MimeUtil.class
com/sun/mail/util/DecodingException.class
com/sun/mail/util/ASCIIUtility.class
com/sun/mail/util/TraceInputStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/BASE64DecoderStream.class
com/sun/mail/util/CRLFOutputStream.class
com/sun/mail/pop3/
com/sun/mail/pop3/AppendStream.class
com/sun/mail/pop3/POP3SSLStore.class
com/sun/mail/pop3/POP3Message.class
com/sun/mail/pop3/TempFile.class
com/sun/mail/pop3/Status.class
com/sun/mail/pop3/POP3Store.class
com/sun/mail/pop3/SharedByteArrayOutputStream.class
com/sun/mail/pop3/Response.class
com/sun/mail/pop3/DefaultFolder.class
com/sun/mail/pop3/WritableSharedFile.class
com/sun/mail/pop3/Protocol.class
com/sun/mail/pop3/POP3Folder.class
META-INF/mailcap
META-INF/gfprobe-provider.xml
META-INF/javamail.charset.map
META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
META-INF/LICENSE.txt
META-INF/javamail.default.providers
META-INF/maven/javax.mail/
META-INF/maven/javax.mail/mail/
META-INF/maven/javax.mail/mail/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/javax.mail/mail/pom.properties
META-INF/mailcap.default
META-INF/mimetypes.default
com/sun/activation/
com/sun/activation/registries/
com/sun/activation/registries/LineTokenizer.class
com/sun/activation/registries/LogSupport.class
com/sun/activation/registries/MailcapFile.class
com/sun/activation/registries/MailcapParseException.class
com/sun/activation/registries/MailcapTokenizer.class
com/sun/activation/registries/MimeTypeEntry.class
com/sun/activation/registries/MimeTypeFile.class
com/sun/activation/viewers/
com/sun/activation/viewers/ImageViewer.class
com/sun/activation/viewers/ImageViewerCanvas.class
com/sun/activation/viewers/TextEditor.class
com/sun/activation/viewers/TextViewer.class
javax/activation/
javax/activation/ActivationDataFlavor.class
javax/activation/CommandInfo.class
javax/activation/CommandMap.class
javax/activation/CommandObject.class
javax/activation/DataContentHandler.class
javax/activation/DataContentHandlerFactory.class
javax/activation/DataHandler$1.class
javax/activation/DataHandler.class
javax/activation/DataHandlerDataSource.class
javax/activation/DataSource.class
javax/activation/DataSourceDataContentHandler.class
javax/activation/FileDataSource.class
javax/activation/FileTypeMap.class
javax/activation/MailcapCommandMap.class
javax/activation/MimeType.class
javax/activation/MimeTypeParameterList.class
javax/activation/MimeTypeParseException.class
javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.class
javax/activation/ObjectDataContentHandler.class
javax/activation/SecuritySupport$1.class
javax/activation/SecuritySupport$2.class
javax/activation/SecuritySupport$3.class
javax/activation/SecuritySupport$4.class
javax/activation/SecuritySupport$5.class
javax/activation/SecuritySupport.class
javax/activation/URLDataSource.class
javax/activation/UnsupportedDataTypeException.class
javax/annotation/
javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class
javax/annotation/CheckForSigned.class
javax/annotation/CheckReturnValue.class
javax/annotation/Detainted.class
javax/annotation/MatchesPattern$Checker.class
javax/annotation/MatchesPattern.class
javax/annotation/Nonnegative$Checker.class
javax/annotation/Nonnegative.class
javax/annotation/Nonnull$Checker.class
javax/annotation/Nonnull.class
javax/annotation/Nullable.class
javax/annotation/OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper.class
javax/annotation/ParametersAreNonnullByDefault.class
javax/annotation/ParametersAreNullableByDefault.class
javax/annotation/PropertyKey.class
javax/annotation/RegEx$Checker.class
javax/annotation/RegEx.class
javax/annotation/Signed.class
javax/annotation/Syntax.class
javax/annotation/Tainted.class
javax/annotation/Untainted.class
javax/annotation/WillClose.class
javax/annotation/WillCloseWhenClosed.class
javax/annotation/WillNotClose.class
javax/annotation/concurrent/
javax/annotation/concurrent/GuardedBy.class
javax/annotation/concurrent/Immutable.class
javax/annotation/concurrent/NotThreadSafe.class
javax/annotation/concurrent/ThreadSafe.class
javax/annotation/meta/
javax/annotation/meta/Exclusive.class
javax/annotation/meta/Exhaustive.class
javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifier.class
javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierDefault.class
javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierNickname.class
javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierValidator.class
javax/annotation/meta/When.class
javax/annotation/CheckForNull.java
javax/annotation/CheckForSigned.java
javax/annotation/CheckReturnValue.java
javax/annotation/Detainted.java
javax/annotation/MatchesPattern.java
javax/annotation/Nonnegative.java
javax/annotation/Nonnull.java
javax/annotation/Nullable.java
javax/annotation/OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper.java
javax/annotation/ParametersAreNonnullByDefault.java
javax/annotation/ParametersAreNullableByDefault.java
javax/annotation/PropertyKey.java
javax/annotation/RegEx.java
javax/annotation/Signed.java
javax/annotation/Syntax.java
javax/annotation/Tainted.java
javax/annotation/Untainted.java
javax/annotation/WillClose.java
javax/annotation/WillCloseWhenClosed.java
javax/annotation/WillNotClose.java
javax/annotation/concurrent/GuardedBy.java
javax/annotation/concurrent/Immutable.java
javax/annotation/concurrent/NotThreadSafe.java
javax/annotation/concurrent/ThreadSafe.java
javax/annotation/meta/Exclusive.java
javax/annotation/meta/Exhaustive.java
javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifier.java
javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierDefault.java
javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierNickname.java
javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierValidator.java
javax/annotation/meta/When.java
org/slf4j/
org/slf4j/helpers/
org/slf4j/helpers/BasicMarker.class
org/slf4j/helpers/BasicMarkerFactory.class
org/slf4j/helpers/BasicMDCAdapter.class
org/slf4j/helpers/MarkerIgnoringBase.class
org/slf4j/helpers/MessageFormatter.class
org/slf4j/helpers/NamedLoggerBase.class
org/slf4j/helpers/NOPLogger.class
org/slf4j/helpers/NOPMakerAdapter.class
org/slf4j/helpers/SubstituteLoggerFactory.class
org/slf4j/helpers/Util.class
org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory.class
org/s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737992/noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder).

The thing is that you have a dependency on the slf4j api and not the slf4j implementation.

Comment: Thank you, that was it!  I knew it was something simple, your Google-fu beats mine!  sorry for the duplicate.