# ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j, logback-classic, spring-logback

I am converting a spring app to spring-boot, using boot-starter-parent version: 2.0.4.RELEASE. When I build using
mvn install, its is going through fine, but when I am trying to run the app using command:`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`, I am getting this exception:
ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

Here are dependencies in my pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.24</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0-alpha4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0-alpha4</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have tried following the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737992/noclassdeffounderror-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder), and using new and old versions of logback (both core and classic) dependencies, and adding the 'slf4j-log4j12' and 'slf4j-simple' but still getting the exception. Stack Trace is:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder
>       at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext (LogbackLoggingSystem.java:285)
>       at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize (LogbackLoggingSystem.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent (LoggingApplicationListener.java:191)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent (LoggingApplicationListener.java:170)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener (SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent (SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent (SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting (EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting (SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:316)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1258)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1246)
>       at com.hbo.esp.MyApplication.main (MyApplication.java:17)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing version of each dependency as follow.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Had the same problem with SLF4J 1.8.0-beta4 and Logback 1.3.0-alpha4. But the above constelation works in my case, thanks! However I would appreciate an updated Logback (assuming the fault is there).

Comment: @phirzel, have you solved this issue for newer versions of Logback? I [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737916/should-we-use-isdebugenabled-while-logging-calculated-data-with-logback) to use it for Slf4j **fluent API** advantages, and have now error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder` on spring boot starting. Appreciates any help