# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder and I don't even have logging in my dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, slf4j

I get the error for org.slf4j even thou I don't even have logging in my dependencies. Maybe this error is caused because I copied over the project ? I cleared everything and started from scratch, only some classes were left unharmed , but I checked and neither of this classes are using Logging . any help ?

POM.xml :

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<!-- TO DO: Add support for Maven WAR Plugin -->
<build>
    <finalName>CRMTest</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!--  Add Maven coordinates forL maven-war-plugin -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Error :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getSingleton(LoggerFactory.java:223)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:120)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:269)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jAdapter.createLocationAwareLog(LogAdapter.java:110)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:81)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<clinit>(DispatcherServlet.java:278)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1032)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
```

Comment: If not you, then some other library is internally bringing logging framework. Check with this command. `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.slf4j`

Comment: The joy of Spring and it's multitude of dependencies:  `at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.<clinit>(DispatcherServlet.java:278)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring needs log4j. Take a look at the log:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

Include slf4j.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this answer which covers your issue very well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3738036/3368558

Basically, spring pulls in a logging facade (slf4j) and you need to provide an implementation so it knows how to do its work.

You could use log4j:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Exactly this: Logging is loosely coupled, actually as one of the first components in Java applications. So there is this interface and you can often choose your implementation. Though you should have one. Indeed Spring expects slf4j, but still you are able to use another implementation than Spring usually depends on.

Answer (score 0):

Read the log - you have missing class dependency.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder

Include the whole slf4j package into your pom.xml and use maven to rebuild the project.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
```